# Map an object containing a boolean to a boolean

Tags: angular, dictionary, get, httpclient

I've seen several examples, but I'm stuck transforming this GET response to an Observable

```
{"userExists:":"1"}
```

The API-Service returns "1" for true or "0" for false. I know I'll have to "map" that somehow...

```
  existsUser(username: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/existsUser`)
      .map()
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

I'm lost what to map example, like accessing the response, look for that field and read the value

(I want to use this Service in a AsyncValidator later)

Comment: `.map (r => r.userExists === "1")` ?

Comment: In fact, you should include `map` in the `pipe`, and use @David's callback: `.pipe(map(...))`.